# Finding Excess-N notation range

Tags: computer-science

The question I am seeking to solve is to find the decimal values in the rage of x to y that can be represented using a 32bit excess-65540 system.

I know that [excess-N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary) means that all values are represented in a positive way such that if you have an excess-65540 system then decimal value of 0 would equal -65540

I am confused as to

1. How to find the range of a specific excess-n notation
2. How to actually find a value of an excess-n notation and determine if it is positive or negative.

My guess for 1 would be a range of -65540 to 65539 for decimals but I am unsure if that is right.
2 I am a little lost on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Invent your own smaller sample problems until you get the idea.

For example, if the question asked about 8-bit excess-17, could you answer it?

Hint 2:  There are 2^32 32-bit values, and each of them corresponds to a different excess-65540 number.

Comment: @sarnold: Thanks.  I used to teach CS classes in grad school :-)

Comment: @sarnold: In fact, I think I said too much.  :-)

Comment: @Nemo, I am still very confused do you think you could help me walk through your example of 8 bit excess-17?

Comment: so 8bit means there are 256 possible combinations so would hte range be -128 to 127?

Comment: @Nemo, consider it a nice graduated assistance -- the hint here, the slightly more detailed hint behind the edited link :) Both are far more useful than my attempts to help without giving away the whole thing. :)

Comment: yea, I guess I am just really confused.

Comment: @Nemo do you think you could at least give me the answer for the range of your example of 8bit excess-17 so I can figure out how that works and apply it to my example? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: @sarnold maybe you could help me out with @nemo 's example and help me find the range of that?

Comment: @Nemo for your example I came up with a range of -17 to 238 is that correct? where 17 would equal a value of 0 and the top range can be 256-17-1 and the lower range is the remainder?

Comment: Well, a base-8 number has a range of 0 (all bits zero) to 255 (all bits one).  In excess-17, 0 represents -17.  1 represents -16.  2 represents -15.  And so on...  So fill that in all the way to 255 (which represents... what?) and you will have your range.

Comment: @draino, consider that the 8-bit values in an excess-17 representation still have 8 bits available to represent unique values. Regardless of what point you choose to call `zero` in that range of expressible values, how many values _can_ be expressed? :)

Comment: @Nemo and @sarnold ...okay so the range would be -17 to 238 , to check you can add them together and you get 255 and then 1 to account for a value of 0 and you get 256 which would be 8 bits correct? Thank you so much for the help by the way